# Why isn't IE8 finding these attributes?

Tags: jquery-selectors, internet-explorer-8, jquery-attributes

I get the alerts and expected behavior in IE 9 and everything else, but no such luck in IE 8.  What could be the cause of this?

```
container.find('[style*="left:"],[data-item-left],[style*="top:"],[data-item-top]').each(function(index){
            // do stuff
    });
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WrKHS/2/)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use [a more generic selector](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/).